How to calculate the power fraction of modes in multi mode waveguide?
Imagine the following scenario:
We have a volumetric light source (where the size of the source is much larger than the wavelength of the light). For example, a candle. The gas that emits the light is several millimeters in size, much larger than the ~600 nm or so wavelength. This is important, because we cannot assume it's a point source. Let's look at the simplified case where the source emits only a single color of light.
At a far away distance (take one meter for convenience) we place a multi-mode fiber, with the end facing towards the light source.
As the fiber end is illuminated it captures some of the power. Which will be distributed over many of its guided modes. I would like to calculate the fraction of the power in each mode. E.g. total power is 1, 1st mode contains 0.63 power units, 2nd mode has 0.10, 3rd has 0.05, etc...
If we know the $E, H$ field at the end of the fiber I could calculate the power fractions of the modes from the overlap integral (the modes are orthogonal). The issue is I don't know how to get the field at the end of the fiber. I don't think we can assume that the light arrives as a plane wave (constant phase front) at the fiber. This is because the emission is coming from an extended region so you get a mix of rays with different phases arriving at the fiber. How to proceed?


You can have a look to S² (spacial and spectral) analysis? The Nicholson principle article where they use an OSA could help you.
